# How to prove the ring of Laurent polynomials over a field is a principal ideal domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Disclaimer: this is a homework question. I'm looking for direction, not an answer.

> Given a field $F$, show that $F[x,x^{-1}]$ is a principal ideal domain.

I'm unsure how to proceed. Would it be better to prove this directly? (ie, let $I$ be an ideal, show that $I = (f)$ for some $f \in F[x,x^{-1}]$). The proof that polynomials are a PID would involve (I imagine) division by remainder and use of degree, both of which don't seem to have obvious parallels for Laurent polynomials. Should I try and devise some parallels and mimic the proof for polynomials? Or is this overkill? (or just wrong?)

**edit 1**: I guess the approach I mentioned above amounts to showing that Laurent polynomials are a euclidean domain (we know that euclidean domain => principle ideal domain, so this would be sufficient) Are they a euclidean domain though? (it seems like this would have been the question if they were, instead of asking if they were a PID).

**edit 2**: I've spat this out, think most parts of it are correct, though it seems kind of ugly/cumbersome (but that might just be me trying to spell things out more than is needed):

> Given a Laurent polynomial $f \in F[x,x^{-1}]$, define its "negative
>   degree" $\deg^-(f)$ to be the largest power of $x^{-1}$ that appears
>   in $f$.
>
> Let $I$ be an ideal of $F[x,x^{-1}]$. Note that $\{x^{-\deg^-(f)}f \mid f \in I\} \subseteq F[x]$. Let $J$ be the
>   ideal in $F[x]$ generated by this set. $F[x]$ is a principal ideal
>   domain, so $J$ is a principal ideal and we have $J = (j)$ for some $j \in F[x]$.
>
> We claim $I = (j)$ (now meaning an ideal of $F[x,x^{-1}]$).
>
> Let $f \in I$. Then $x^{-\deg^-(f)}f \in J$, meaning $f = x^{\deg^-(f)}g$, where $g = x^{-\deg^-(f)}f$ is in $J$. Because $g \in
> J = (j)$, there exists $g' \in F[x]$ such that $g = g'j$, and thus $f = (x^{\deg^-(f)}g')j$ is a multiple of $j$, so $f \in (j)$.
>
> Let $f \in (j)$. Then $f = gj$ for some $g \in F[x,x^{-1}]$. But note
>   that $j = x^{-\deg^-(f')}f'$ for some $f' \in I$, so $f = gx^{-\deg^-(f')}f'$, so $f$ is a multiple of an element of an ideal
>   $I$, so $f$ itself is in $I$.
>
> This shows $I = (j)$. So an arbitrary ideal of $F[x,x^{-1}]$ is
>   principal, so $F[x,x^{-1}]$ is a principal ideal domain.

I kind of feel like I still don't "get" the proof (I more-or-less see how each part works with the others but I'm having trouble seeing the bigger picture), though this may be due to a poor handle on ideals in general.

Comment: I like the proof you included very much, except for the fact that I don't quite see why $j = x^{-\text{deg}^-(f')}f'$ for some $f' \in I$. i.e. I don't see why that $f'$ has to exists in $I$.

Comment: I only see that $j$ is a linear combination of elements $f' \in I$, but that that doesn't mean that it's a multiple of any one such $f'$. If $I$ would be a principal ideal, then you could conclude this, but that is exactly what we're trying to prove.

Comment: Come to think of it, it seems your key point in the segment: "Let $f \in (j)$. ... so $f$ itself is in $I$." is redundant. That is: you don't need $j$ to be of the form $X^{-\deg^-(f')}f'$ for $f' \in I$ to still have $j \in I$. It already follows from the fact that $j$ is a linear combination of $f' \in I$ with coefficients in $F[X,X^{-1}]$.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman The OP made a small mistake when assumed $j = x^{-\deg^-(f')}f'$ for some $f' \in I$, but $j$ is a linear combination of such things with coefficients in $F[X]$ and this immediately leads to $j\in I$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536624

Answer (score 13):

Polynomial ring over a field $k$ is a PID. Notice that $S^{-1}k[x]=k[x,x^{-1}]$, where $S=\{x^i:i\in \mathbb N\}$. Now use the fact that [localization of a PID is a PID](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536624/is-the-localization-of-a-pid-a-pid).

Comment: From the linked question: "the ideal $I$ has the form $S^{−1}J$ with $J$ an ideal of $A$". I'm having trouble seeing why this is.

Comment: Second answer seems to me pretty clear. Tell me what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: The thing I'm talking about is the very first sentence of the second answer. It's stated as if it's obvious but I'm not seeing it...

Comment: If you have ideal $I$ and you want to find ideal $J$ take generators of $I=<a_i/s_i>_i$ and then $J=<a_i>$.

Answer (score 2):

1st HINT: Given an ideal $I$ of $F[x,x^{-1}]$, what can you say about $I\cap F[x]$? How is the information you obtain related to $I$?