# What the rings between Principal Ideal Ring and Field of fractions are?

Tags: ring-theory

Prove that all of the rings, which mediate between principal ideal ring $K$ and the field of fractions $Q$, are the principal ideal ring.

Comment: Does "mediate between" mean that the ring, say $R$, is contained in $Q$ and contains $K$? I.e. $K \subseteq R \subseteq Q$?

Comment: Yes. Can you help?

Comment: Related quasi duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536624/is-the-localization-of-a-pid-a-PID which might help also

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $ $ They're localizations since $\,K[a/b] = K[1/b],\,$ by $\,(a,b) =1\,\Rightarrow\, ra+sb = 1\,\Rightarrow\, ra/b + s = 1/b$

Answer (score 2):

$K = \mathbb{Z}$

$R = \{\frac{a}{2^n} : a \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

$Q = \mathbb{Q}$

If I understand your question here is an counter example.

Comment: Isn't $R$ here also PID?

Comment: Yes. I read you question as that there only rings between a principle ideal ring and it's field of fractions are THE principle ideal ring to mean there are no proper rings between. If you are asking if any in between must also be A principle ideal ring that is true.

Comment: I don't think this should have been downvoted.  The question is poorly worded and this is also what I thought the OP was asking.