# Is this ring a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be the $k$-subalgebra of $k(t)$ generated by the set $k[t]$, of all polynomials, and a pair of rational functions: ${1\over{t-1}}$ and ${1\over{t-2}}$. Is the ring $R$ a PID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the localization of a PID a PID?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536624/is-the-localization-of-a-pid-a-pid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rough outline of how you might prove this: Given any ideal $I$ of $R$, consider the polynomials in the ideal, $I_1=I\cap k[t]$. Show that $I_1$ is an ideal of $k[t]$, hence principal in $k[t]$. Then show that its generator is also a generator for all of $I$ in $R$.

The basic property you'll use is that for every element $f\in R$, there is an $m$ so that $(t-1)^m(t-2)^mf\in k[t]$.