# show $\mathbb{C} [x,y]/(xy-1)$ is a principal ideal domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

I've got to show that $A:=\mathbb{C} [x,y]/(xy-1)$ is a principal ideal domain

I know that $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ and that this a subfield
of $\mathbb{C}[t]$ which is a PID. So then $A$ is also a PID.

But however I've got to work with the canonical inclusion map  $i: \mathbb{C}[x]  \hookrightarrow A$ in order to show then $I \cap \operatorname{Im}(i) \neq \{0\}$ for every ideal $I \neq \{0\}$. I have no idea why I need this.

Comment: $A$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb{C}[t]$, because $A$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{C}[t]$ and neither $A$ nor $\mathbb{C}[t]$ are fields (check the inverse of $t+1$).

Comment: Also, being a subring of a PID does not automatically make it a PID.

Comment: As you noted, it's isomorphic to $\mathbb C[t,t^{-1}]$, which is the localization of $\mathbb C[t]$ at the powers of $t$. Then [a nonzero localization of a PID is a PID](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/536624/29335)