# Prove that a ring of fractions of $\mathbb Q[x]$ is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let
> $$
> R = \left\{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\mid f(x),g(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x], g(x)\not=0\right\}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(x).
> $$
> Show that $R$ is a principal ideal domain.

My approach was to first prove that for any integral domain $S$ we have
$$
\begin{equation}
\text{Frac}(S[x])\cong\text{Frac}(S)(x)
\end{equation}
$$
and so $R\cong\mathbb{Q}(x)$, hence it's a field and so a PID. But I couldn't come up with a proof of this statement. Is this the right approach or is there a better way?

Comment: Why didn't try to prove that $R$ is a field *directly*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb Q$ is a field $\implies \Bbb Q[X]$ is a PID. Then as $R=S^{-1}(\Bbb Q[X])$ where $S=\Bbb Q[X] \setminus \{0\}$ and localization of a PID is a PID, hence, $R$ is also a PID.

Comment: Hey, thank you! Do you have a link for a proof that a localization of PID is a PID? I haven't seen this result before...

Comment: @14159 It's trivial to prove, anyway can see a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/536632/674271)

Comment: If $R$ is an integral domain and $S=R\setminus\{0\}$, then $S^{-1}R$ is a field.